Named return and code coverage in Solidity
Context
While aiming at 100% code coverage and 100% SolHint compliance I am experiencing some difficulties in combining the gas-named-return-values rule from SolHint, with the branch coverage of the function below, whilst generating a correct code that does not overshadow a private variable in the function return statement.
Violate SolHint: gas-named-return values
If I remove the named return like so:
function released(address account) public view override returns (uint256) {
    return _releasedAmount;
  }

SolHint says:

136:3  warning  GC: Named return value is missing - Index 0                                                                                                                                  gas-named-return-values

and code coverage by LCOV is happy:

Violate code correctness
If I include the named return and provide valid syntax
Warning (2519): This declaration shadows an existing declaration.
212 |   function released() public view override returns (uint256 _releasedAmount {
    |                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Note: The shadowed declaration is here:

   |
40 |   uint256 private _releasedAmount;

And then the tests breaks down because the  uint256 private _releasedAmount variable is overwritten.
Violate code coverage
If I create a local variable in the function named releasedAmount and assign the value of _releasedAmount to it, the LCOV code coverage says the last line is not covered, as shown in the image below:

Even though I test it with:
    address payable investorWallet0 = payable(address(5));
    uint256 returnAmount = 40;
    uint256 startBalance = 7;

    // give investor some start balance
    deal(investorWallet0, startBalance);

    // Give the amount to be returned into the _paymentSplitter.
    _paymentSplitter.deposit{ value: returnAmount }();

    // Ensure the investor is a payee of the conhtract.
    _paymentSplitter.publicAddPayee(investorWallet0, returnAmount);

    // Signal th epayment can be released.
    _paymentSplitter.release(investorWallet0);
    assertEq(investorWallet0.balance, startBalance + returnAmount);
    assertEq(_paymentSplitter.released(investorWallet0), returnAmount);
  }

Question
How can I have named returns whilst still ensuring LCOV recognises the return statement is covered, while returning a private variable that can not be re-initialised?
Note
In in the images it is not a private variable named _releasedAmount but something that can be returned directly. The question is about the cases where it is a private variable.
